# How do I connect web app to key vault in Azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I've done everything from giving both vault and app god powers and what not, created a multitude of endpoints and VPN's, and god knows what. Still, when passing a keyvault reference to the Web App config, it is unable to resolve saying I have insignificant privalages. Basically, I'm trying to make it so I can retrieve secrets from my vault so I don't have to embed them in my code. I am using the free trial. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but at the same time, given the ungodly amount of power my Web App and Vault have now I'm not so sure.... :/ I am trying to do this without using the CLI, as it appears kaput (it doesn't recognize my UPN and when I use object ID I get that AK10032 warning).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the reason I cannot access the key vault using an endpoint is because using a vnet resource to access resources is for paid accounts. I have to set network to allow all connections for the Web App to be able to connect to a vault.

As for the latter part of my issue, I figured out that for some reason vs code was not processing the environment variable, so I had to implicitly pass the needed param, so problem solved there.